# Xbox 360 4 GB Game Compatibility

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

Is it true that some games will not play on a Xbox 360 4 GB?  In particular, I'm wondering about Modern Warfare 2.  Since I "know" about computers, my relatives want console recommendations, as if I knew.

Comment: where did you hear this?

Comment: @TZHX - I'm not sure where I heard this, but it seemed possible (if not plausible) since it doesn't have a hard drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, all games will play on all Xbox 360's. The only limitation that I'm aware of is that some games require a hard drive for some features. For example, in Halo Reach (and also Halo 3 and ODST, although I'm not positive on that), playing co-op in campaign or firefight requires a hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

The only game that I know *requires a hard drive to run* is Final Fantasy XI. As Andy mentioned in his answer, some games may require a hard drive for certain features. In either case, publishers are required to state any storage requirements on the back of the box, so you can always check there.

Answer (score 1):

Also to be aware, original XBox games require a Hard Drive, as the emulation software is installed on a partition of the drive.