# Where to find a list of Xbox 360 games requiring HDD?

Tags: xbox-360

Where can I find a fairly comprehensive list of 360 games that require HDD for full functionality (i.e. multiplayer, downloadable content, etc.)?

Also, is there any, and if so, please tell where, a list of games that install game contents on HDD in order to reduce loading times? Do all 360 games install on HDD?

Are there any 360 games that will not run on Xbox 360 4GB Arcade?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11691/xbox-360-4-gb-game-compatibility/11708#11708

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know all games can be installed to decrease loading times. It also decreases the use of your disc drive and disc spinning. So it has a benefit that your console will last longer. Or at least it should.

I know of no list, but I know that Final Fantasy XI is one of the games that **must** be installed.

Comment: Is is possible to install a 360 game onto a 4GB Arcade?

Comment: @sarmmackie In theory, games can probably be installed on a 4GB Arcade, however most games are 5-6GB so there wouldn't be enough room for them.

Comment: Wolfenstein: The New Order is a mandatory install of 8GB minimum on 360. GTA V also requires the first disk to be installed.